# Change default applications used by gnome-open, exo-open, xdg-open, gvfs-open and kde-open

Tags: gnome, kde, configuration, xfce, open-files

How to change the applications associated with certain file-types for `gnome-open`, `exo-open`, `xdg-open`, `gvfs-open` and `kde-open`?

1. Is there a way by editing config files or by a command-line command?
2. Is there a way to do this using a GUI?

For both questions: How to do it per user basis, how to do it system-wide?

Comment: For kde-open and other KDE apps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165618/how-to-change-file-association-for-files-opened-in-dolphin-from-command-line-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all done with MIME types in [various databases](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/2.32/mimetypes-database.html.en). `xdg-mime` can be used to query and set user values.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem today, but more towards the gnome/cinnamon side of things.

You can query and change the default mime type like this:

```
gvfs-mime --query inode/directory

gvfs-mime --set inode/directory nemo.desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer, here are the incantations for the impatient that should cover many typical use cases:

Figure out the mime type of your file:

```
xdg-mime query filetype somefile.pdf
```

will result in `application/pdf`.

Set a default application to handle it:

```
xdg-mime default qpdfview.desktop application/pdf
```

where I use qdfview's desktop definition as the program to handle PDFs.