# wget/curl command not getting the contents of a file from a link

Tags: terminal, curl, wget, download, links

I have a .bin file that I would like to download, it's around 10GB in size. The file can be found here (any of the 4 download links): `http://mazajak.inf.ed.ac.uk:8000/#embedding-page`. When I download the file using wget or curl on a private server that I have, I get a 10GB file that is not a .bin file (does not have any extension), but if I click download on my local computer from the website, it clearly shows that it's downloading a .bin file. Any idea where I'm going wrong here? What I'm doing is right-clicking on the "download" hyperlink and pasting it infront of the wget/curl command.

these are example commands I'm running:

`wget http://mazajak.inf.ed.ac.uk:8000/get_sg_250`

`curl -o http://mazajak.inf.ed.ac.uk:8000/get_sg_250`

Comment: Just because the file ending is not `.bin` does not mean its not the right file. What step did you take to verify that it's a "wrong" file? Checksum?

Comment: File extensions don't have the same meaning they do on Windows - [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266999/why-does-linux-use-file-extension-to-decide-the-default-program-for-opening-a-fi)